# How to add MRI sections side by side in the MedDream DICOM viewer?

Tags: mri

I'm trying to read MRI results. I want to have images side by side, like in this video: https://youtu.be/uO3xmPLrvvM?t=119

I'm using MedDream viewer online. It's the most convenient and I can't install most other viewers, because I'm using Linux, and most are for Windows.

This is the MRI file I'm trying to view:
https://www.dicomlibrary.com/meddream/?study=1.3.6.1.4.1.44316.6.102.1.20210804165813624.36372704986493662224

I've tried searching for answers, but only found this and a few other videos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H70FE4Tnggw

In some videos they appear to click "multiview", choose 1x2, and then drag the MRI exam results from the left to the newly appeared window. But when I do this, it just gets it back to the default one-window view.

This is the video of what happens:
https://i.imgur.com/bRiLryW.mp4

My goal is to be able to view the Axial projection and see where it is on the Saggital projection. A line should appear, like in the first video that I linked.

P.S. I'm almost figured it out. If I click MPR and then choose one of the options there, I can then add different sections to different windows. I still haven't learned all the aspects of it though.

Comment: I don't think this site is a good venue for this question. It sounds like you're looking for support for a specific software - check the documentation or support resources for that software.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn't a tech support site. "How to" questions about software applications aren't on topic here. Please see [What topics can I ask about here](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

I usually batch-convert DICOM files to jpegs using ImageJ (in Ubuntu). This way you can open multiple windows side-by-side. The size is also much smaller, for example, 3.9MB for all 7 upright MRI sequences of 32 slices each.